# netCDF array size too big

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, netcdf, netcdf4

so i am trying to unpack a netCDF file and i have gotten to a point where i have put the variables that i am interested in, in a np array. However, my problem comes in for the size of the array that i am trying to analyse. The folowing are the variables and their sizes:

```
_parameters ()
globalx (1, 231)
globaly (1, 231)
globaltime (6,)
vz (6, 100, 1, 231)
uz (6, 100, 1, 231)
u (6, 1, 231)
v (6, 1, 231)
ustz (6, 100, 1, 231)
```

I am interested in vz,uz and ustz (explanation on what they contain... (the number of iterations, nz, ny, nx) i am not interested in ny and it holds no value.

so the question is now can i make the size to (the number of iterations, nz, nx) and unpack nz and nx per iteration.

Thanks

here is my code,

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ncfile = 'xboutput.nc'
jan = Dataset(ncfile, more = 'r')

#print (file.variables)

_parameters = jan.variables['_parameters']
globalx = jan.variables['globalx'].units
globaly = jan.variables['globaly'].units
globaltime = jan.variables['globaltime'].units
vz = jan.variables['vz'][:]
uz = jan.variables['uz'][:]
ustz = jan.variables['ustz'][:]
v = jan.variables['v'][:]
u = jan.variables['u'][:]

for i in jan.variables:
    print (i,jan.variables[i].shape)

vz_ar = np.array(jan.variables['vz'])
u_ar = np.array(jan.variables['u'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is what the [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/) package was designed to solve. Especially because of its [integration with dask](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html), xarray is the ideal tool for working with large netcdf files with many dimensions.

Try opening your data with xarray instead

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('xboutput.nc')
```

Then work with the data directly via the xarray API. Xarray's [broadcasting rules](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/computation.html#compute-broadcasting) make it very easy to operate on data with different combinations of dimensions.